# I can't get the 15th weekday in ruby

Tags: ruby

I cant get the next 15th day but not the working day.

```
DateTime.now.next_day(+15).strftime('%d %^B %Y')
```

how can i get the next 15th weekday?

Comment: Can you clarify? If 15th day is weekend you want to continue until hit monday?

Comment: [`business_time`](https://github.com/bokmann/business_time) is a ready-to-go solution for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're just adding 15 days to the current date. What you want is to adjust the date:

```
date = DateTime.now

if (date.mday > 15)
  date = date.next_month
end

date = date.next_day(15 - date.mday)
```

Where that adjusts to be the 15th of the next month if it's already past the 15th of the current month.

Now this can be extended to be an Enumerator:

```
def each_mday(mday, from: nil)
  from ||= DateTime.now

  Enumerator.new do |y|
    loop do
      if (from.mday > mday)
        from = from.next_month
      end

      from = from.next_day(mday - from.mday)

      y << from

      from += 1
    end
  end
end
```

Which makes it possible to find the first day matching particular criteria, like being a weekday:

```
each_mday(15, from: Date.parse('2019-06-14')).find { |d| (1..5).include?(d.wday) }
```

Where that returns July 15th, as June 15th is a weekend.

The `from` argument is optional but useful for testing cases like this to ensure it's working correctly.

Comment: 15th working day would be 12th April excluding all weekends. But the code out put is : 2019-04-15T22:18:36+00:00

Comment: Added filtering options to find weekdays only, or whatever else might need to be applied as a constraint.

Answer (score 1):

```
15.times.reduce(Date.civil 2019, 03, 24) do |acc, _|
  begin
    acc += 1
  end while [0, 6].include? acc.wday
  acc
end
#⇒ #<Date: 2019-04-12 ((2458586j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to add 15 business days from the current date. You can go with iGian or Aleksei vanilla ruby answers or use [business_time](https://github.com/bokmann/business_time) gem:

```
15.business_days.from_now
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to get next Monday if you hit Saturday or Sunday. Since `wday` gives you `0` for Sun and `6` for Sat, you can use it to as a conditional to add days towards Monday.

```
def date_add_next_week_day(days)
  date = (Date.today + days)
  date += 1 if date.wday == 6
  date += 1 if date.wday == 0
  date
end

date_add_next_week_day(15).strftime('%d %^B %Y')
```

Comment: I tried the above code but its not excluding weekends.

Comment: ah ok, so you to add only business days

Answer (score 0):

If I get the point you need to find the 15th day after a specified date, skipping weekends.

One possible option is to define the `skipping_weekend` hash like this, considering [Date.html#wday](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-wday):

```
skip_weekend = { 6 => 2, 0 => 1}
skip_weekend.default = 0
```

Then:

```
next15 = DateTime.now.next_day(15)
next15_working = next15.next_day(skip_weekend[next15.wday]).strftime('%d %B %Y')
```

Now if `next15` falls on a working day, `next15_working` is the same day (hash defaults to `0`), otherwise it skips 2 days if Saturday (6th week day, hash maps to `2`) or 1 day if Sunday (0th week day, hash maps to `1`)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that, given a starting date, `ds` (a `Date` object), and a positive integer `n`, the problem is determine a later date, `dt`, such that between `ds+1` and `dt`, inclusive, there `n` weekdays.

```
require 'date'

def given_date_plus_week_days(dt, week_days)
  wday = dt.wday
  weeks, days = (week_days + {0=>4, 6=>4}.fetch(wday, wday-1)).divmod(5)
  dt - (wday.zero? ? 6 : (wday - 1)) + 7*weeks + days
end
```

The variable `wday` is assigned to the day of week for the start date, `dt`. The start date is moved back to the previous Monday, unless it falls on a Monday, in which case it is not changed. That is reflected in the expression

```
wday.zero? ? 6 : (wday - 1)
```

which is subtracted from `dt`. The number of week days is correspondingly adjusted to

```
week_days + { 0=>4, 6=>4 }.fetch(wday, wday-1)
```

The remaining calculations are straightforward.

```
def display(start_str, week_days)    
  start = Date.parse(start_str)
  7.times.map { |i| start + i }.each do |ds|
    de = given_date_plus_week_days(ds, week_days)
    puts "#{ds.strftime("%a, %b %d, %Y")} + #{week_days} -> #{de.strftime("%a, %b %d, %Y")}"   
  end
end
```

```
display("April 8", 15)
Mon, Apr 08, 2019 + 15 -> Mon, Apr 29, 2019
Tue, Apr 09, 2019 + 15 -> Tue, Apr 30, 2019
Wed, Apr 10, 2019 + 15 -> Wed, May 01, 2019
Thu, Apr 11, 2019 + 15 -> Thu, May 02, 2019
Fri, Apr 12, 2019 + 15 -> Fri, May 03, 2019
Sat, Apr 13, 2019 + 15 -> Fri, May 03, 2019
Sun, Apr 14, 2019 + 15 -> Fri, May 03, 2019
```

```
display("April 8", 17)
Mon, Apr 08, 2019 + 17 -> Wed, May 01, 2019
Tue, Apr 09, 2019 + 17 -> Thu, May 02, 2019
Wed, Apr 10, 2019 + 17 -> Fri, May 03, 2019
Thu, Apr 11, 2019 + 17 -> Mon, May 06, 2019
Fri, Apr 12, 2019 + 17 -> Tue, May 07, 2019
Sat, Apr 13, 2019 + 17 -> Tue, May 07, 2019
Sun, Apr 14, 2019 + 17 -> Tue, May 07, 2019
```